# How do I package PyTesseract using PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-tesseract

this is my first time creating an executable like this so let me know what I can do to help you help me!

To create my python project I installed something called Pillow, PyTesseract, and PyInstaller so that I could read text from an image and output a file. I used PyInstaller on the main python file (scheduler.py) that imported a secondary file (parser.py) which imported PyTesseract from PIL.

The executable runs on my laptop which was used to write the program in the first place (so where I used pip to install Pillow, PyTesseract, and PyInstaller). This was obvious enough to me but when I zipped the dist folder created from PyInstaller and moved it to a different computer I get the following error.

[Error message after running my executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzPH7.png)

It seems to me PyTesseract is not being bundled with my executable.

My question is how I can get it to do so, so that my executable is truly portable? My full code is here https://github.com/iamchrisllaga/spireScheduler.

UPDATE:

I think I got it. I just made sure the Tesseract-OCR folder libraries was in the same directory as the executable.